# How to use a CommonJS module in React with Webpack?

Tags: reactjs, node-modules

I'm trying to install this React library:
[html-2-jsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-2-jsx)

Problem is, i don't know how to import it into React. The description says:

> To use the Node.js module, require('htmltojsx') and create a new instance.

When i try to just require it in the React component, ESlint tells me:

> File is a CommonJS module. It may be converted to an ES6 module.

Of course, when i try to run Webpack, i get errors.

The errors i get in Webpack:

```
 Can't resolve 'child_process' in 
 'C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter_cms\public\node_modules\xmlhttprequest\lib'
```

And few errors of this kind:

```
 Can't resolve 'fs' in 
 'C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter_cms\public\node_modules\cssstyle\lib'
```

How can this be done? To be honest, i find it a bit weird, that a library made for react, doesn't support ES6 import functionality.

Comment: What errors are you getting from webpack?

Comment: See my edit, i've added the errors

Comment: Are you using VS Code as your editor? I think the `File is a CommonJS module` message is a VS Code thing. If so, it's really just a suggestion, you can `import htmltojsx from 'htmltojsx` instead of using `require()`. Just a newer syntax.

Comment: Yes i'm using Visual Code. About the import: It works, but only when i implement what mpontus suggested in the selected solution

Comment: My gut feeling is that some "node" code that can only work in NodeJS is being used (or perhaps just "processed by webpack") which is generating the warnings/errors.  What I've seen is an ```"exclude" : /node_modules/``` pattern (in webpack.config.js) to prevent the webpack/babel loaders from looking at all of the files in your directory instead of just **your source** files.  But you've already got this working by stubbing out some node modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to your webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  node: {
    fs: 'empty',
    child_process: 'empty'
  }
};
```

The warning you are seeing has nothing to do with those errors. If you'd like to fix the warning then it may require some context on where the warning occurs.